# Check condition whether all checkboxes are 'unchecked'

Tags: jquery, html

I have seven checkboxes as below. I'm trying to do 3 things as follows:
1)When 'any' checkbox is 'checked' then the remaining '1-6' should be 'unchecked'. 
2)When any one among '1 to 6' checkbox is 'checked' then 'any' checkbox should be 'unchecked'. 
3)If I 'check' numbers and then 'uncheck' all of them then 'any' checkbox should be 'checked'

I was able to do 1) and 2) using jquery but not 3).

I was unable to check for the condition whether all the checkboxes "1 - 6" are 'unchecked'.

Html:

```
<input name="deal_any" type="checkbox">any

<input name="deal" type="checkbox">1
<input name="deal" type="checkbox">2
<input name="deal" type="checkbox">3
<input name="deal" type="checkbox">4
<input name="deal" type="checkbox">5
<input name="deal" type="checkbox">6
```

jquery:

```
$("input").click(function(){
name=$(this).attr("name");
match = name.match(/any/);
if( match != null)
{
if($(this).is(':checked'))
{
   $('input[name="deal"]').attr('checked', false);
}
}
else
{
if($(this).is(':checked'))
{
   $('input[name="deal_any"]').attr('checked', false);
}
}
});
```

Can anyone show me how this can be done?
Sorry if my explanation is not clear.

I will appreciate any efforts and thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: So you're saying that 'any' should become checked if you first check a number and then uncheck it?

Comment: yes, If I check few numbers and them uncheck all of them.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this

```
var da = $('input[name="deal_any"]'); // any checkbox
var di = $('input[name=deal]'); // other 6
// when any checkbox changes
da.change(function() {
    // if checked then uncheck all others
    if(this.checked){
        di.prop('checked',false);
    }
});
// when other 6 checkboxes change
di.change(function(){
    // if none are checked then check "deal_any" checkbox - else uncheck
    da.prop('checked',$('input[name=deal]:checked').length === 0);
}).change(); // trigger on page load
```

http://jsfiddle.net/W8QSW/

You can make it universal doing it like this

```
var da = $('input.class_one'); // checkbox with name that ends with any
var di = $('input.class_two'); // other checkboxes that don't have any
// when any checkbox changes
da.change(function() {
    // if checked then uncheck all others
    if(this.checked){
        di.prop('checked',false);
    }
});
// when other 6 checkboxes change
di.change(function(){
    // if none are checked then check "deal_any" checkbox - else uncheck
    da.prop('checked',$('input.class_two:checked').length === 0);
}).change(); // trigger on page load

​
```

Comment: If I can use it for another set of checkboxes with different names

Comment: You should have stated that in your original post @codebeginner

Comment: I'm sorry I just realized that I did not mention it.

Comment: is there something in common with your other checkboxes?

Comment: "class_one" for 'any' checkbox and "class_two" for "1-6" checkboxes. This is common for another set of checkboxes

Comment: @codebeginner i just updated the code using classes...  All you have to do is change the selectors that are cached to the variables.  Only thing is if they are on the same page, you will have to specify the context to separate them

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($('input[name=deal]:checked').length==0) {
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/8MWgj/

Comment: Shouldn't it be [name='deal'] ?

Comment: @HristoYankov Single quotes are optional in this case.

Comment: The fiddle doesn't answer the OP's question. Just unchecked all of them, the alert fired, but the any box was not checked.

Comment: @JayBlanchard  Well, I figured OP could do that little part himself. He just asked to check for the condition. But if you insist: http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/8MWgj/1/

Answer (score 2):

This'll satisfy all conditions listed by the OP -

```
$('input[name="deal"]').change(function() {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').not($(this)).prop('checked', false);
    if($('input[name="deal"]:checked').length == 0){
        $('input[name="deal_any"]').prop('checked', true);
    } 
});
```

Based on the OP's desire to be able to re-use this without explicit names for the checkboxes he could also do this -

```
$('input[name="deal"]').change(function() {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').not($(this)).prop('checked', false);
    if($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length == 0){
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').eq(0).prop('checked', true);
    } 
});
```